# Finite outer automorphism groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

It is a theorem of Gopal Prasad (which I hope I am not misquoting...) that lattices in higher rank linear semi-simple Lie groups have finite outer automorphism groups. Is there some other reasonable class of groups with this finiteness property?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a result of Fr\'ed\'eric Paulin: a hyperbolic group with Kazhdan's property (T), has a finite outer automorphism group. See Outer automorphisms of hyperbolic groups and small actions on R-trees. Arboreal group theory (Berkeley, CA, 1988),
331–343, Math. Sci. Res. Inst. Publ., 19, Springer, New York, 1991.

Comment: Thanks! Of course this begs the question of where such groups would come from...


Comment: More generally, relatively hyperbolic groups that don't split over elementary subgroups have this property by a result of Drutu-Sapir, see Theorem 1.12 in http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/0601.5305

Comment: @Igor Rivin: there are lots of relatively hyperbolic groups with no elementary splittings. What kind of groups are you looking for?

Comment: @Alain: I read your math review of Frederic's paper, which sheds some light on the hyperbolic/property T question (although you carefully say that it has been "stated" by Gromov, not "proved" -- has that situation been changed)? Also, you mention a conjecture that groups with property T have finite outer automorphism groups. Has there been any progress on this?

Comment: @Igor Belegradek: Just to check: are you saying that all such groups have property T? Is there a good reference for this?

Comment: @Alain: In fact, I found the following paper:
http://www.yann-ollivier.org/rech/publs/trips.pdf
which produces a group with property T but infinite Out()

Comment: @Igor Rivin: any countable group embeds into some Out(G) where G has property (T), see http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/0605.5553. In fact, I seem to recall that Minasyan-Osin showed that any countable group can be realized as Out(G) where G has property (T), but I cannot find a reference at the moment.

Comment: @Igor Rivin: I meant to say that a relatively hyperbolic group G that doesn't split over elementary subgroups must ahve finite Out(G).

Comment: @Igor Belegradek: thanks! Is there a reference for the "doesn't split -> finite Out" statement?

Comment: I gave the reference to "doesn't split -> finite Out" above :). Again it is Theorem 1.12 in front.math.ucdavis.edu/0601.5305. The paper I think appeared in Topology.

Comment: @ Igor: There is a simple example due to Yves Cornulier: Let $M_n(\mathbb{Z})$ be the additive group of $n$-by-$n$ matrices with integer coefficients. Let $SL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ act on the left by matrix multiplication; it is known that the semi-direct product has property (T) for $n\geq 3$. Now let $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ act by matrix multiplication on the right on $M_n(\mathbb{Z})$; since left commutes with right, the latter action extends to an action on $G$ by outer automorphisms.

Comment: Updated link for @IgorBelegradek's comments: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0601305, _Groups acting on tree-graded spaces and splittings of relatively hyperbolic group_, by Cornelia Drutu and Mark Sapir

Answer (score 5):

The theorem Igor Belegradek mentions is a more general form of the theorem (due collectively to Bestvina, Feighn, Paulin, and Rips) that a one-ended hyperbolic group has infinite outer automorphism group only if it splits over a two-ended subgroup. See

M. Bestvina, M. Feighn, 
Stable actions of groups on real trees. 
Invent. Math. 121 (1995), no. 2, 287-321.